# How to get JSON data into ember / handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new with ember... all stuff related to JSON I can find is using ember-data, which I am not going to be using (we have an xml not REST api).

All I am trying to do at the moment is load my sideNav.json data into my application template.

sideNav.json:

```
[
    {
        "label": "Overview",
        "pageClass": "nav-home",
        "iconClass": "icon-overview",
        "link": "index.html"
    }, {
        "label": "Total Energy",
        "pageClass": "nav-totalEnergy",
        "iconClass": "icon-meter",
        "link": "totalEnergy.html"
    }
]
```

template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div id="sideNav">  
        <ul>
            {{#each model}}
            <li {{bindAttr href="link"}}>
                <a {{bindAttr class="pageClass"}}>
                    <i {{bindAttr class="iconClass"}}></i><p>{{label}}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

At the moment, I am making this work like so:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      {
        label: "Overview",
        pageClass: "nav-home",
        iconClass: "icon-overview",
        link: "index.html"
      },
      {
        label: "Total Energy",
        pageClass: "nav-totalEnergy",
        iconClass: "icon-meter",
        link: "totalEnergy.html"
      }
    ];
  }
});
```

But I would like to keep this data in the separate JSON file, I was thinking about just using $.ajax() to get the data, but i don't think that is the best approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it just going to be static data, or are you planning on making calls to the server?  If that static json file is something you can't modify use Ember.$.ajax(). If you can modify the json file, just change it to a js file, include it in the page, and make it something like this...

```
 App.SideNavFixture = [
   {
    "label": "Overview",
    "pageClass": "nav-home",
    "iconClass": "icon-overview",
    "link": "index.html"
   }, {
    "label": "Total Energy",
    "pageClass": "nav-totalEnergy",
    "iconClass": "icon-meter",
    "link": "totalEnergy.html"
   }
 ];

 App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     return App.SideNavFixture;
   }
 });
```